# Error: Must declare the scalar variable 5

Tags: sqldatasource

I'm battling to make the transition from Classic ASP to ASP.NET.  I have the code below that works if I hard code the start date and end date but gives the error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Must declare the scalar variable "@SDate" when I use parameters.  There are may references to this error when I search for it, but I just can't find one that helps me. The page is designed to display two text boxes for the user to enter the start and end date for the search and then click the button to have the data exported to Excel.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" ContentType="text/html" ResponseEncoding="iso-8859-1" EnableViewStateMac="false"%>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.SqlClient" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Export results to Excel</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<script language="C#" runat="server">

    protected void btnExportToExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        ExportToExcel();
    }

    //Export to Excel from a GridView
    protected void ExportToExcel() {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=MyFiles.xls");
        Response.Charset = "";
        this.EnableViewState = false;

        System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
        System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        gvData.RenderControl(htw);

        Response.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }

    public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control) {
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
Export results to excel
</body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <h1>
            My Files</h1>
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%; height: 12%">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Start date</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="StartDate" runat="server" Width="200px" Text="2000/01/01"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>

                    End date</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="EndDate" runat="server" Width="200px" Text="2012/11/01"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>

                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnExportToExcel" runat="server" Text="Export to Excel" onclick="btnExportToExcel_Click" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:KpraxConn %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT Results.IDNumber, [FirstName], [LastName], [DOB], [Gender] FROM [Results] LEFT JOIN Login ON (Results.IDNumber=Login.IDNumber) where ([LogDate]>=@SDate and [LogDate]<=@EDate) ORDER BY [LastName]">
        <asp:SelectParameters>
            <asp:FormParameter FormField="StartDate" Name="SDate" DefaultValue="2000/01/01" />
            <asp:FormParameter FormField="EndDate" Name="EDate" DefaultValue="2012/11/04"  />
        </asp:SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

    <asp:GridView ID="gvData" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="IDNumber" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource" PageSize="5">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="IDNumber" HeaderText="IDNumber" ReadOnly="True"/>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName"/>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName"/>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="DOB" HeaderText="DOB"/>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="Gender" HeaderText="Gender"/>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    </form>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the button click event call this method

protected void ExportToExcel() 
{

```
 Response.Clear();
 Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridView1.xls");
 Response.Charset = "";
 Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
 StringWriter StringWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
 HtmlTextWriter HtmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(StringWriter);
 GridView1.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter);
 Response.Write(StringWriter.ToString());
 Response.End();
```

}

Comment: Hi. Thanks.  I replaced my code with yours.  Now I get this error: The name 'StringWriter' does not exist in the current context.  I'm not sure how your code is an answer to my original problem.